# Restart Apache using Ant script for both unix and windows Systems?

Tags: apache, ant

I searched and found some ques as ** how to restart apache using nant script ** and tried similar code but got some message..i tried this code

```
<exec executable="${APACHE_HOME}/bin/httpd.exe">
    <arg value="-k"/>
    <arg value="restart"/>
</exec>
```

OUTPUT:

```
apache-restart:
     [exec] [Tue Nov 15 19:58:18 2011] [error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : No installed ser
vice named "Apache2.2".
     [exec] Result: 2
```

And the reason for this is i guess Apache is not installed as a windows service.

I tried both but both have problems:

1) my cursor kept blinking and next statement echo was not reached.

```
  <target name="test"  depends="init"> 
    <exec executable="${APACHE_HOME}/bin/httpd.exe">
    </exec>
    <echo message="hello "/>
 </target>
```

OUTPUT:

```
test:
```

2)where is this taskkill file present ??

```
<target name="test"  depends="init"> 
                <exec executable="taskkill /im httpd.exe">
                </exec>
                 <echo message="hello "/>
 </target>
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run progra
"taskkill \im httpd.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, install the service first with `httpd.exe -k install`

Or you can execute `taskkill /im httpd.exe` to kill apache and `httpd.exe` to start it again. You may want to add `/f` switch to `taskkill` also.

Comment: Thanks but..Its already installed by a Java Based Application as a sub-installer Web Server ..so i am not supposed to change that configuration.

Comment: @user1037728, well then execute "taskkill /im httpd.exe" to kill apache and "httpd.exe" to start it again. You may want to append /f switch to taskkill also.